# Alguna forma de saber que IP hace una peticion a un puerto abierto?

Tags: php, cmd

tengo una MAQUINA o PC EQUIX con el puerto 1433, y a veces mi hosting le cambian la IP a otras IPs, me pregunte si hay o existe alguna manera de saber el historial de peticiones entrantes al puerto 1433? que permita conectar con el puerto 1433 el sql server.

o algo aparte de hacer ping + link como puedo obtener  la IP real de un dominio o hosting.

consegui esta **netstat -n 3** pero sigue sin funcionarme

IPtools me servira de algo?

Comment: Dos equipos, dos sistemas operativos, dos IPs, dos puertos... ¿El historial de quién para quién? Normalmente los ISPs domésticos ofrecen IPs dinámicas, ¿hablas de un hosting con IPs dinámicas?.

Comment: respondido su pregunta edite mi pregunta

Comment: La petición se puede atorar en el ruteador, el corta fuegos y -menos común- en el servicio. Depende **para qué**

Comment: necesito saber la ip real solicitante para que conecte con un hosting